# How can one open Adobe Reader with VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, adobe-reader

I want to programmatically fill in some fields in a form in PDF format.

I tried this code:

```
Set objAdobe = CreateObject("AcrobatReader.Application")
objAdobe.Visible = True
```

I get the "ActiceX component can't create object" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OLE automation interface is **only provided by [Adobe Acrobat](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/)**, not Adobe Reader.

If you have Adobe Acrobat installed, you can launch it from VBScript like this:

```
Set oAcrobat = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
oAcrobat.Show
```

For a complete reference of Acrobat's automation API, see the "OLE Automation" section of [this document](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_api_reference.pdf).

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have Adobe Reader. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the windows API ShellExecute function.
Not sure of the VB syntax (this works in FoxPro)...

```
DECLARE INTEGER ShellExecute IN shell32.dll ; 
  INTEGER hndWin, ; 
  STRING cAction, ; 
  STRING cFileName, ; 
  STRING cParams, ;  
  STRING cDir, ; 
  INTEGER nShowWin
cFileName = "d:\MyDocs\myfile.pdf"
cAction = "open"
ShellExecute(0,cAction,cFileName,"","",1)
```

...but the user will have to fill in the fields by hand.